# Scrape football predictions from bing

Tags: javascript, python, html

When you use bing search and search for *fussball bundesliga* bing displays you the last week the current week and the next week. The games are normally on weekend. if none of the games for the actual week is already played you will get probabilities for each team to win, loose or have a draw.

I can already get the results/predictions from the page that don't need to be expanded, since they are in the html on load. To see more I need to expand that view somehow (can bee seen by the circle in the picture). In a human controlled browser this is easy.[image: site on load]

The problem is that clicking on that arrow issues an `onclick()` event which executes a javascript. So I thought using somethin that has javascript support might help. Till now I could not get the missing games since I'm not able to programmatically click that arrow and load the page. Here is my Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString
import requests
import sys  
from lxml import html
import spynner
from time import sleep

import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=fussball+bundesliga"

    sess = dryscrape.Session()
    sess.visit(url)
    response = sess.body()

    dryscrype_soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
    #test = dryscrype_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"tab_3_dynamic"})
    dryscrape_actual_week =   dryscrype_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"sp-full-29"})
    dryscrape_text = [i for i in dryscrype_soup.recursiveChildGenerator() if type(i) == NavigableString]
    dryscrape_all_text = dryscrape_actual_week[0].findAll(text=True)


    browser = spynner.Browser(debug_level=spynner.DEBUG)
    browser.show(True,True)
    browser.load(url)
    browser.runjs("sj_evt.fire('ExpandClick', '29', '');",True)

    #browser.wk_click(".//*[@id='sp-expandTop-more-29']", wait_load=True)
    #browser.wk_click_ajax(selector=".//*[@id='sp-expandTop-more-29']")
    browser.wait_load()

    markup = browser._get_html()
    spynner_soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"lxml")
    spynner_actual_week = spynner_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"sp-full-29"})
    spynner_all_text = spynner_actual_week[0].findAll(text=True)
```

Don't bother the imports, I tried several things already. I tried microsofts azure api, but this only delivers links, not these predictions. When you have a look into the html that is parsed or the variables `spynner_all_text` and `dryscrape_all_text` you will notice that they contain only the results from the non expaned webpage. Hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: I know that I'm bothering the imports here, but [Selenium](http://Selenium-python.readthedocs.org) is able to handle javascript button events very nicely. You may also find it easier to work out where those predictions are coming from and make a javascript call to that instead?

Comment: I thought about selenium already. I used it already and see now that there is a headless version available as well. Since I want this to run on a headless system. How do I find out where this stuff really comes from? I was playing around with firebug a little to dig deeper. But there is so much other stuff loading and updating that I can't rellay see what is important there. I'm not used to webdev.

Comment: So I used Slenium now which made it very easy to get the stuff I need

Comment: Glad to hear it :)